# OpenVPN as proxy

Tags: proxy, openvpn

## What I want:

I want to connect to OpenVPN, and my predefined list of IP-addresses get routed through that connection (`tun0`). All other traffic is unaffected (goes through `eth0`).

## What I have tried:

- I wanted to make sure `ufw` wasn't the issue, so I disabled it (`ufw disable`).
- I wanted to make sure `iptables` wasn't the problem, so I reset it, resulting in:

`$ iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

(which should pretty much accept any connection)

## What I managed to do:

- I can connect to the OpenVPN server
- I can ping to the OpenVPN server host (`10.8.0.1`)
- I can ping to other connected hosts (not needed for this use-case, but I can)

## What didn't work:

- Accessing anything other than in the OpenVPN network (`10.8.0.x`)

## How I configured stuff:

On the client-side, I am manually setting the routes (in the conf-file):

```
route-nopull
route 54.175.222.246 255.255.255.255
route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

(`54.175.222.246` is the IP address of `http://httpbin.org/`)

This actually sends the stuff to the OpenVPN server; logs:

```
Jan  1 12:02:08 bare2 ovpn-server[25265]: client-deskserver/77.251.109.156:45958 UDPv4 WRITE [229] to     [AF_INET]77.251.109.156:45958: P_DATA_V1 kid=0 DATA len=228
Jan  1 12:02:08 bare2 ovpn-server[25265]: client-deskserver/77.251.109.156:45958 UDPv4 WRITE [229] to [AF_INET]77.251.109.156:45958: P_DATA_V1 kid=0 DATA len=228
Jan  1 12:02:08 bare2 ovpn-server[25265]: client-deskserver/77.251.109.156:45958 UDPv4 READ [101] from [AF_INET]77.251.109.156:45958: P_DATA_V1 kid=0 DATA len=100
Jan  1 12:02:08 bare2 ovpn-server[25265]: client-deskserver/77.251.109.156:45958 UDPv4 READ [101] from [AF_INET]77.251.109.156:45958: P_DATA_V1 kid=0 DATA len=100
Jan  1 12:02:08 bare2 ovpn-server[25265]: client-deskserver/77.251.109.156:45958 TUN WRITE [64]
Jan  1 12:02:08 bare2 ovpn-server[25265]: client-deskserver/77.251.109.156:45958 TUN WRITE [64]
Jan  1 12:02:08 bare2 ovpn-server[25265]: client-deskserver/77.251.109.156:45958 TUN READ [123]
Jan  1 12:02:08 bare2 ovpn-server[25265]: client-deskserver/77.251.109.156:45958 TUN READ [123]
```

However, either the server doesn't redirect it to the public internet connection, **or** whatever the http server sends back, isn't received / redirected by the OpenVPN server. I have no idea which of those is the case, and I have no idea how to fix either one of them. (Most posts I found, were about sending *all* traffic through the OpenVPN, instead of *specific* traffic; those that *were* about specific traffic, talked about allowing stuff through `iptables`, but those things didn't help)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

After about half a day of searching on the web, I finally came across [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1112851#p1112851).

In short, all I had to do, was this:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

(I also had to enable ipv4 forwarding, but I already did that long ago